# How can you send a mouse event to another program without moving the cursor?

Tags: java

Doing it with the Robot class doesnt seem to work for me, unless there is a way without moving the cursor.
So what i need is a way to get the Component of another program (by creating a new MouseEvent) or just another way to use the Robot class.

Thanks already.

Comment: Please show some code samples of what you tried.  See [ask].

Comment: Getting a component of another program by mouse event, doesn't sound the best solution. If the "other program" is actually run by the same JVM instance, but a different frame, there are clean ways within Swing to do that.

Comment: Is this also possible if the other program is run by another jvs instace?

Answer (score 1):

Use `MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation()` to get the mouse position right before you move it, then move it (and do whatever you'd like), and then return the mouse to its previous location.

The alternative is fairly complicated, and even more complicated if it's not a Java program - you'd need to provide much more information about that program, and your odds of getting a clean answer would be slim.